# some confusion regarding delegates

Tags: objective-c, ios

```
@protocol msgRcvdFrom <NSObject>

@optional
-(void) msg:(NSString *)msg from:(NSString *)from;
.
.
. 
if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(msg:from:)])
{
    [delegate msg:body from:user];
}
```

this is my delegate and two different classes are using it, when respondsToSelector is called will both classes will be notified? or if I want to notify one class at a time. Please clear this confusion.

Comment: two classes can refer it in code, but only one object can be the delegate at the moment.

Comment: both my classes are doing this [myAppDelegate setDelegate:self]; and this is my delegate property @property (strong, nonatomic) id<msgRcvdFrom> delegate; ... how to differentiate?

Comment: when one object did `[myAppDelegate setDelegate:self]`, then the another one that was delegate loses it. because delegate is only one. it's timing

Comment: will this a proper approach if i do this for id<msgRcvdFrom> delegateForClassOne and id<msgRcvdFrom> delegateForClassTwo

Comment: personally I don't think that's good idea as it's out of purpose of protocol and delegation of Objective-c. I would try notification instead. so your myAppDelegate posts notifications and your 2 classes observe and pick the notifications. just in my opinion

Comment: thanks a lot for nice replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delegate` usually is an object (declared as `id< msgRcvdFrom>`).
So.. when you call `respondToSelector` on `delegate` you are asking to that particular object if it has the method or not!

Comment: both my classes are doing this [myAppDelegate setDelegate:self]; and this is my delegate property @property (strong, nonatomic) id<msgRcvdFrom> delegate; ... how to differentiate?

Comment: In this way only the last one is set. You have to create a NSMutableArray and add the delegate..

Comment: create a NSMutableArray and add the delegate .. sorry i didn't get your point

Comment: if a property is defined as `id<someprotocol>` (as in your case) can have only one object set. When you set it twice, the first one is .. "lost".... If you want to have more then one delegate, you have to create an array (private), two public methods (addDelegate and removeDelegate), so when you need to call the delegate methods, you put your code inside a for loop...

Comment: will this a proper approach if i do this for id<msgRcvdFrom> delegateForClassOne and id<msgRcvdFrom> delegateForClassTwo